# $\mathbb{Z}\rtimes\mathbb{Z}$ is left-orderable but not right-orderable.

Tags: group-theory, order-theory

I was working in the following problem:

**Prove that $\mathbb{Z}\rtimes\mathbb{Z}=\langle x,y\mid x^{-1}yx=y^{-1}\rangle$ is left-orderable but not right-orderable.**

Where a group $G$ is right-orderable if there exists a total order $<$ such that $\forall~x,y,z\in G~x<y\Rightarrow xz<yz$, and it is left-orderable if there exists a total order $<$ such that $\forall~x,y,z\in G~x<y\Rightarrow zx<zy$.

Proving that $\mathbb{Z}\rtimes\mathbb{Z}$ is not right-orderable is easy:

- $1<y\Rightarrow y^{-1}<1\Rightarrow x^{-1}yx<1\Rightarrow yx<x\Rightarrow y<1$, which is a contradiction.
- $1>y\Rightarrow y^{-1}>1\Rightarrow x^{-1}yx>1\Rightarrow yx>x\Rightarrow y>1$, which is a contradiction.

However I can't prove that $\mathbb{Z}\rtimes\mathbb{Z}$ is left-orderable. I know that there are some results that solve this as an immediate consequence, but I want to find the explicit order (if possible) or to know what is the easiest result (the one which needs less previous results) that solves this.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: See the reference [here](https://math.berkeley.edu/~mattht/papers/lo-groups.pdf), page $1$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde This page does not contain a proof, the statement itself can be found in OP.

Comment: @markvs I only said at page $1$ is a  "reference", which is [KM96]. I suppose one can find more references for a proof.

Comment: @DietrichBurde KM96 is a book of significant size, The statement has a few line proof. But yes, it can be found there.

Comment: @markvs  Indeed I have found the solution there, thanks for your help :)

Comment: @DietrichBurde sorry and thanks, just a confusion with the names, hope you can forgive me :)

Comment: @Marcos: You may want to answer your question and then accept the answer, otherwise the question will be listed as "unanswered".

Comment: @markvs Done, maybe you can read it to check if there are no mistakes.

Comment: Actually, every left-orderable group is also right-orderable. Namely, if $<$ makes $G$ into a left-ordered group, then the relation $<'$ where $x<'y$ iff $x^{-1}<y^{-1}$ makes $G$ into a right-ordered group.

Comment: @GeoffreyTrang Yeah, the proof in the question actually shows it is not *bi-orderable*, as at different points they are multiplying on the left and the right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that $yx=xy^{-1}$ implies that every element of $\mathbb{Z}\rtimes\mathbb{Z}$ is of the form $x^\alpha y^\beta$ with $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Hence we can define the order $x^{\alpha_1} y^{\beta_1}>x^{\alpha_2} y^{\beta_2}$ if $\alpha_1>\alpha_2$ or $\alpha_1=\alpha_2$ and $\beta_1>\beta_2$, let us see that this order makes $\mathbb{Z}\rtimes\mathbb{Z}$ a left-ordered group. Let $a,b,c\in \mathbb{Z}\rtimes\mathbb{Z}$, then $a=x^{a_1}y^{a_2}$, $b=x^{b_1}y^{b_2}$ and $c=x^{c_1}y^{c_2}$ for some $a_1,a_2,b_1,b_2,c_1,c_2\in\mathbb{Z}$.

We have to prove that $a<b$ implies $ca<cb$. Notice that $a<b\Leftrightarrow x^{a_1}y^{a_2}<x^{b_1}y^{b_2}\Leftrightarrow a_1<b_1$ or $a_1=b_2$ and $a_2<b_2$. On the other hand $ca=x^{c_1}y^{c_2}x^{a_1}y^{a_2}=x^{c_1}x^{a_1}y^{(-1)^{a_1}c_2}y^{a_2}=x^{a_1+c_1}y^{a_2+(-1)^{a_1}c_2}$ and  $cb=x^{b_1+c_1}y^{b_2+(-1)^{b_1}c_2}$. Then, if $a_1<b_1$, we have $a_1+c_1<b_1+c_1$ which implies $ca<cb$ and if $a_1=b_2$ and $a_2<b_2$ then $a_1+c_1=b_1+c_1$ and $a_2+(-1)^{a_1}c_2<b_2+(-1)^{b_1}c_2$, which implies $ca<cb$.

Comment: Now you need to accept your answer.

Comment: @markvs I will, but I can't do it untill tomorrow.